# How to load animaton on DirectX 10

Tags: keyframe, directx-10

I am a beginer on game development. I wont write simple game with DirectX 10 and need to load animation like man playing cards. I don't know how to strat. As I know I must create my own file format and convert from some other format to it, but I don't know how. So please help me and if it is possible give some code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DirectX SDK features a sample application with source code called [Skinning10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416429(VS.85).aspx) that implements character animation.

The NVIDIA Direct3D SDK shows off [Skinning with Dual Quaternions](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/direct3d/samples.html).

Also, you may want to have a look at the [CAL3D Character Animation Library](http://home.gna.org/cal3d/).

Comment: Thanks for links, they helped me